# How to change open with options in navigator depending upon name of the resource?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on eclipse RCP application which implements `CommonNavigator` view to display navigator. I have few `LinkedResources` in navigator that link to files on the file system with custom extension. These custom extension files are opened in custom editor as well as in `TextEditor`.

One of the file named `default.ext` will be common to all the projects and I want to keep it read only. Is it possible to open file in custom editor only? For ex. `Default.ext` should be opened in only custom editor, however `Test.ext` should be opened in custom editor as well as text editor.

This way I could handle save action in my editor depending upon file name and keep the file read only.

Is there any other way to keep files read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: not possible in the way you describe.

Long answer: if somebody really wants to modify a file then there's no way or need to stop this. What you can do is either (1) hide the file from user or (2) set *Read-only* flag to discourage users from modifying the file.